# Get-Eventlog - To monitor specific event ID

Tags: get-eventlog, event-id

I have requirement to monitor specific event ID for specific set of workstations. 
Event ID Monitor : To monitor Specific event ID for specific set of workstations

```
$Workstations = gc c:\NotBackedUp\Workstation.txt
foreach ($Workstation in $Workstations)
{
    $events = Get-EventLog -ComputerName $Workstation -LogName "Application" | Where-Object     {$_.EventID -eq "2"} | Format-List
}
$events >> C:\NotBackedUp\Test.txt
```

But I can get error as below,

> Get-EventLog : The network path was not found. At line:6 char:15
>   + ...   $events = Get-EventLog -ComputerName $Workstation -LogName "Applica ...
>   +                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-EventLog], IOException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.IO.IOException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetEventLogCommand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$Workstations = gc c:\NotBackedUp\Workstation.txt
foreach ($Workstation in $Workstations)
{
    $events = Get-WinEvent -ComputerName $Workstation -LogName "Application" | Where-Object     {$_.EventID -eq "2"} | Format-List
}
$events >> C:\NotBackedUp\Test.txt

By doing above script, this will not give any error, but takes longer time than usual. 
Now, any suggestion to filter this option and give output in short time.  Your suggestions are really appreciated.